# How to avoid `dotnet-script` swallowing arguments

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-script

I'm using `dotnet-script` for the first time, I'm getting some undesirable behavior I don't know how to fix.

My script expects a "-v" argument, but instead of that getting passed through, dotnet-script swallows it and prints out its own version number. This happens for the most basic of scripts:

```cs
#!/usr/bin/env dotnet-script

Console.WriteLine($"Hello World:\n{string.Join('\n', Args)}");
```

Example input/output:

```
> ./script.csx "hi again"
Hello World:
hi again

> ./script.csx "hi again" -v
1.4.0
```

How can I avoid `dotnet-script` swallowing arguments?

*I know I could avoid using the -v argument in my script, but I'd like to avoid this behavior entirely so I don't come across other swallowed arguments.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used `dotnet-script` before, but after a quick search I found [this source](https://discoverdot.net/projects/dotnet-script#:%7E:text=Passing%20arguments%20to%20scripts%20All%20arguments%20after%20--,arguments%20before%20--%20are%20processed%20by%20dotnet%20script.)  which states:

> *"All arguments **before** `--` are processed by dotnet script and all arguments **after** `--` are passed to the script"*

So it sounds to me like perhaps you just need to add `--` before the arguments that you want passed to your script:

```
> ./script.csx -- "hi again" -v
```